# Tensorflow version conflict between Spyder and Anaconda-Prompt

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, spyder

I downloaded the TensorFlow version 1.14.0 from Anaconda Prompt.

`pip install tensorflow==1.14.0`

[image]

When I check the version of Tensorflow from Spyder it shows like this

```
   import tensorflow as tf
   print("Tensorflow Version : ",tf.__version__)
```

[image]

Why Anaconda prompt and Spyder show the different versions of TensorFlow?